# How to check first character in string and how to send that string into an array in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

friends.

I have an array and it contains some string values.
ex: array name="All_array"

Now i want to check all values in that array for first character of a string.

if a String starts with character 'a' then move that string to array called "A_array".
if a String starts with character 'b' then move that string to array called "B_array".

How to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var splitArrays = {};
for(var i = 0; i < All_array.length; ++i){
    var firstChar = All_array[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if(!splitArrays[firstChar + '_array'])
        splitArrays[firstChar + '_array'] = [];
    splitArrays[firstChar + '_array'].push(All_array[i]);
}
```

This will take every element in `All_array` and put them into an object containing the arrays indexed by the first letter of the elements in `All_array`, like this:

```
splitArrays.A_array = ['Abcd','Anej','Aali']
```

etc...

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svjJ9/

Comment: is it better to use `.substr(0,1)` or `.charAt(0)` ? is there one way better than the other ? Thanks !

Comment: This is fine. I need to push 'Abcd', 'Anej', 'Aali' into separate array.

Comment: I actually have no idea - I've never used `charAt`.. Dunno why, actually.. I'd like to know if there's a difference, too :D

Comment: Why use `substr` instead of `substring`, when the first one isn't supported by version 3 browsers yet the exact same results can be obtained with both?

Comment: @Niklas version 3 browsers?? hahaha, sorry, I can't avoid to laugh. So we shouldn't use javascript because 8086 machines don't support it :S.

Comment: @Edgar where did I say you can't use JavaScript? What I find quite funny is that you so aggresively try and give an argument why it is not worth adding those extra 3 characters of `ing` there, when your code wastes a lot of space the way you've written it.

Comment: @Thor Jacobsen: i didn't find any answer on the web, i eventually posted the question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579774/whats-the-difference-between-substr0-1-or-charat0

Comment: @Niklas, the goal of stackoverflow is to solve real problems. Answers are NOT written for being seen with a microscope or to try to find irrelevant "problems" on them. My answer was not aggresive, I swear your comment was funny to me, and I was joking about it. These answers solve the problem (sorry, but IE 3 is not a problem today), so issues like yours are irrelevant. What matters in an answer is to work, to be understandable for the person who asks, and to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be this:

```
for(var i=0; i<All_array.length; i++){
   var firstChar = All_array[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase();
   var arrayName = firstChar + "_array";
   if(typeof(window[arrayName]) == 'undefined') window[arrayName] = []; //Create the var if it doesn't exist
   window[arrayName].push(All_array[i]);
}
A_array = []; //empty the array (cause you wanted to 'move')
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Why use `substr` instead of `substring`, when the first one isn't supported by version 3 browsers yet the exact same results can be obtained with both?

Comment: version 3 browsers? hahaha. No comments :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `each()` and `charAt`:

```
$.each(All_array,function(i,s){  
    var c = s.charAt(0).toUpperCase();                
    if(!window[c + '_array']) window[c + '_array'] = [];
    window[c + '_array'].push(s);
});
```