# What's the difference between .substr(0,1) or .charAt(0)?

Tags: javascript, performance, string

We were wondering in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579439/how-to-check-first-character-in-string-and-how-to-send-that-string-into-an-array) if there was a real difference between the use of `.substr(0,1)` and the use of `.charAt(0)` when you want to get the first character (actually, it could apply to any case where you wan only one char).

Is any of each faster than the other?

Comment: You could try profiling them...also, the answers might be browser dependent...

Comment: You could make a benchark (http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: @Felix Kling: thanks for the link, bookmarked!

Comment: Both return "string" type. `typeof 'something'.charAt(0)` => "string"; `typeof 'something'.substr(0,1)` => "string"

Comment: @JMax: you can also do a `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[0]`

Comment: @Salman A: thanks for the tip but it's *rather slow* > http://jsperf.com/substr-or-charat/3 :)

Comment: @SalmanA: This does not work in all browsers...

Comment: @Felix: which one? it should work according to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) -- edit -- or may be not :(

Comment: @SalmanA: As it says, it is part of ECMAScript 5 and not all browsers (especially IE) support it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Measuring it is the key!

Go to http://jsperf.com/substr-or-charat to benchmark it yourself.

substr(0,1) runs at 21,100,301 operations per second on my machine, charAt(0) runs 550,852,974 times per second.

I suspect that charAt accesses the string as an array internally, rather than splitting the string.

As found in the comments, accessing the char directly using string[0] is slightly faster than using charAt(0).

Comment: Max's answer was for Java, not JS...  Also you appear to have your results the wrong way around!

Comment: That first number is suspiciously high.  Are you sure that's right?  Though that link is awesome.

Comment: This shows how insanely fast Chrome 14 is by the way – charAt runs almost 4x faster than in Chrome 12...

Comment: This is the opposite (charAt is faster than substring) but the method was the right one and thanks @Aleks G for the explanation of the loop. Thanks everybody for your comments and you answers.

Comment: @Rich: I've added `a[0]` tests [here](http://jsperf.com/substr-or-charat/2)... on chrome, `a[0]` is almost as fast as `a.charAt(0)`.

Comment: That's interesting, I would have assumed that a[0] would be quicker, as it looks like a direct access. Benchmarking is so useful!

Comment: Ah, I'm getting a[0] to be faster than a.charAt(0) now, which makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Unless your whole script is based on the need for doing fast string manipulation, I wouldn't worry about the performance aspect at all. I'd use `charAt()` on the grounds that it's readable and the most specific tool for the job provided by the language. Also, `substr()` is not strictly standard, and while it's very unlikely any new ECMAScript implementation would omit it, it could happen. The standards-based alternatives to `str.charAt(0)` are `str.substring(0, 1)` and `str.slice(0, 1)`, and for ECMAScript 5 implementations, `str[0]`.